# Difficult with fancyhdr and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

Premise: I'm new with fancyhdr.
I defined the following fancy style:

```
\lhead{}
\chead{\slshape\leftmark}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

which correctly draw the chapter number and name, top line, the bottom line, and the page number, in all the page except the first of each chapter.

So, I redefined the plain style in the following way:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}
```

which correctly draw the top line, the bottom line, and the page number in the first page of each chapter (note: the plain style miss the chapter number and name of the fancy style)

Now, I have a problem with the table of contents.
The first page of the toc has the plain style (without the chapter number and name), but the following pages have the fancy style (with chapter number and name).
How can I apply the plain style to ALL the page of the toc?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What document class are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using the `book` class, I presume that everything in the front matter is intended to be under the `plain` pagestyle:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[C]{\slshape\leftmark}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}

\appto\frontmatter{\pagestyle{plain}}
\appto\mainmatter{\pagestyle{main}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

%%% fill with some mock text
\def\testsec{\section{B}\lipsum}
\def\test{\chapter{A}
  \testsec
  \testsec
  \testsec
  \testsec
  \testsec
  \testsec
  \testsec
  \testsec
  \testsec
  \testsec
}
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\test
\end{document}
```

However, I'd recommend against the footrule.

Answer (score 5):

Try this in the preamble of your real document

```
\usepackage{etoc}
\renewcommand{\etocaftertitlehook}{\pagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\etocaftertochook}{\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

(edit replaces `\pagestyle` with `\thispagestyle` in the line above)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{}
\chead{\slshape\leftmark}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}


\usepackage{etoc}
\renewcommand{\etocaftertitlehook}{\pagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\etocaftertochook}{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{ONE}

\section {A}

\chapter{TW0}

\section {B}

\newcount\cnta
\loop
\chapter{\the\cnta}

\ifnum\cnta<50
\advance\cnta 1
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it on purpose that even pages numbers appear in the left side of the header, rather than in the centre of the footer?

Comment: @Bernard this is an artefact due to the succession of almost empty chapters. Each `\chapter` modifies the page style. By the way, I should have intialized the `\ctna` counter at `3`.

Comment: I have this error: `\etocaftertochook undefined` on this line: `\renewcommand{\etocaftertochook}{\thispagestyle{plain}}`

Comment: @Andrea `\etocaftertochook` is available since release `1.07g` of `2013/10/13`. Perhaps you have `TexLive2013` from a year ago, without subsequent updates. In that case just insert `\thispagestyle{plain}` immediately after `\tableofcontents`, or update your installation.