# Fancyhdr and TOC

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I posted a question a couple of weeks ago about my header-footer design and now it looks right on point: thanks for that. I'm having, though, problems with my ***table of contents***, because it has two pages and default style doesn't work for me then (as you can see, this 0 is very unpleasant):

### Photo I

[image: 0 doesn't procede there]

---

I've taken a look at [Changing only the header for Table of Contents pages with package fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484953/changing-only-the-header-for-table-of-contents-pages-with-package-fancyhdr) post, and I've worked something like this in my styles.sty file:

```
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{nor}{% <===========================================
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\lastrightxmark}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\lastleftxmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thechapter}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{+0.025\textwidth}
}
\fancypagestyle{toc}{% <===========================================
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\lastrightxmark}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\lastleftxmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[]{+0.025\textwidth}
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}\extramarks{}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\extramarks{\thesection}{#1}}
```

And then, in the .tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{styles}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{.55cm}

\pagestyle{nor}
\begin{titlepage}
Some text
\end{titlepage}

\pagestyle{toc}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{nor}
\chapter{Els nombres enters}
SOME TEXT.

\end{document}
```

Which doesn't work for me, because (1) redefining of the chapterMark/sectionMark is lost and so it messes with the style of other pages; (2), by Photo II and Photo III, it seems like it never changes from \pagestyle{toc}; and (3), TOC header doesn't work either, because it shows the same output as Photo I. Photo IV is from a functional header from before these changes I made.

Hope you can help me. Thanks.

***UPDATE:*** I worked a little bit on my styles.sty code, and this is how it is at the moment. main.tex remains intact. Two things: is there any way to make the code more elegant? It seems a little off.
The other, as I commented to Pieter, \renewcommand{\chaptermark} and \renewcommand{\sectionmark} still don't work as expected, output is the same as in Photo II. Furthermore, I tried to put these two commands inside \fancypagestyle{} definition and above them: it hasn't worked in any way.

```
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{nor}{% <===========================================
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\lastrightxmark}}
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\lastleftxmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thechapter}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{+0.025\textwidth}
    \fancyheadoffset[RE,LO]{+0.0\textwidth}
}
\fancypagestyle{toc}{% <===========================================
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
    \fancyhead[RE]{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{}
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textsc{Índex}}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[]{+0.025\textwidth}
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}\extramarks{}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\extramarks{\thesection}{#1}}
```

---

### Photo II

[image]

### Photo III

[image]

### Photo IV

[image]

Comment: Put a `\newpage` before `\pagestyle{nor}`. In general it is advised to put `\newpage` before page style changes, unless you can be sure that a new page was  already started.

Comment: Hello Pieter, I'm in a book environment, and so I assume chapters always start on a new page. I worked a little bit on my code, but \renewcommand{\chaptermark} and \renewcommand{\sectionmark} are still giving me headaches. I'll update my post.

Comment: That is true, but when you issue the `\pagestyle{nor}`, it is still on the last page of the TOC. So that means that when the last page of the TOC is constructed, `nor` is the page style that the page builder uses. After that the `\chapter` starts the new page.

Comment: It was actually working, only that I had to set \fancyhead[RE,LO,RO,LE] to empty, my fault. Still, \renewcommand{\chaptermark} and \renewcommand{\sectionmark} don't work as expected. A working solution is to put them inside \fancypagestyle, but the following error appears: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \ps@nor"

Comment: So it seems on page 7 the header (with section title and section number) disppears.
I cannot reproduce that, I do get the header. So it may be just coincidental with how your subsections fall on the page. Would it be possible to email a more complete document to me? My email address is in the fancyhdr documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a private communication with @Mario I could solve both issues. For future lookup I will give the solutions to both problems here.

**1. Why did the last page of the TOC get the wrong page header?**

The `pagestyle{nor}` command was executed before the last page of the TOC was output. The output of that page occurs when the `\newpage` that is implied by the next `\chapter` command is executed. The `\tableofcontents` itself does not have a `\newpage` at the end; if you wished, you could add additional text after it on the same page.

Now when the page is output, the new pagestyle has already been set, so that pagestyle is used. The solution is to add a `\newpage` before the `\pagestyle{nor}`.

**2. The `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` seem not to be working**

It appears Mario was using `fancyhdr` version 3.10. In all versions of fancyhdr before version 4, the initialisation is done when the first `\pagestyle{fancy}` (or one of its derived pagestyles) is given, including the initialisation of `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`. So the first `\pagestyle{nor}` in the document initialised these and therefore the definitions given in the `styles.sty` got lost. In `fancyhdr` version 4 this is no longer the case, so this gives the right results.

Fortunately there is a simple solution, other than switching to version 4:
In `styles.sty`, put `\pagestyle{nor}` before the `\chaptermark` definition. Now first the initialisation is done and then the given definitions overwrite the default definitions.

```
\pagestyle{nor}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}\extramarks{}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\extramarks{\thesection}{#1}}
```